# Copy file from a GCP Compute Engine on project A to a bucket on project B causes 403 Insufficient Permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, gsutil

I'm trying to copy a file from a Compute Engine on GCP in project A to a bucket in Project B.

Compute Engine in project A runs with a service account which has Storage Admin privileges in Project B.

When running the command (from within a shell on the Compute Engine) I get: AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission.

Does anyone have any pointers for me?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer. It turns out my service account also needed Storage Admin rights on project A.

After providing the Storage Admin rights on project A the problem was solved.